# Dev Server restart repeatedly results in: code: 'EADDRINUSE'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, nodemon

I find myself having to cycle through the following pattern in terminal while using nodemon:

```
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1253:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:9) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 8081
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

^C
owner@G700:~/PhpstormProjects/shopify/from_tch$ sudo lsof -i :8081
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    28169 owner   19u  IPv6 26913489      0t0  TCP *:tproxy (LISTEN)

owner@G700:~/PhpstormProjects/shopify/from_scratch$ kill -9 28169

owner@G700:~/PhpstormProjects/shopify/from_scratch$ nodemon server.js
[nodemon] 1.19.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
> Ready on http://localhost:8081
```

nodemon is supposed to handle restarting the server on changes, so I'm not sure why it seems to keep conflicting with itself and forcing me to kill processes. Does anyone know if this is a misconfiguration, or how to overcome this? I'm on Lubuntu 18.04 and my terminal is this:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```